# finding closest prime number

Tags: c, primes, compile-time

This is not an easy question to ask.
I'm writing a code which would for ask a "n". Then ask for n numbers and finally print that closest prime number to one of them is how far.
The problem is the compile time should be less than 4 secs and I can't get it under 5 s.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int f (int n){
    int i;
    int a;
    int b;
    int dif=0;
    for ( i = 2 ; i<n ; i++) 
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 0; 
    return 1;

}
int main (){
    int dif=0;
    int difall=10000;
    int a;
    int b;
    int input;
    long long input2;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int i;
    for (i == 1;i<input;i++){
        scanf("%d",&input2);
        dif=0;
        while (1==1){
        a=input2+dif;
        b=input2-dif;
        if (f(a) == 1 && a>=0){
            if (dif<difall)
                difall=dif;
            break;}
        if (f(b) == 1 && b>=0){
            if (dif<difall)
                difall=dif;
            break;}
        dif++;

    }
    }
    printf("%d",difall);
}
```

Comment: The compile time? Or the running time?

Comment: Think you mean the *run* time, not compile time. Outside of that, your question is somewhat confusing. Not really getting *"... print that closest prime number to one of them is how far."*. And we have no earthly idea what input you're providing which is giving you a TLE on whatever coding site you pulled this problem from.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I suggest you learn to format your code a little better (for example use consistent indentation, as well as adding empty lines to split it into paragraphs). Also please learn to use nice and descriptive names for functions and variables. And last of course comment the code to explain what complicated pieces of code do and how they work.

Comment: Apart from 2 and 3 all prime numbers are of the form 6n ± 1.  That will allow you to avoid checking a lot of numbers.

Comment: @WhozCraig I knew it was confusing. For example you first enter 3 meaning you have 3 numbers. Then you enter 26,50,99. Then program returns 2 because the  prime number with the smallest difference to any of the numbers is 101 that is 99+2. While the closest to 26 is 31 and closest to 50 is 57.

Comment: @rossum Is that a theorem or a conjecture? If it's proven, what is it called? I'm just curious.

Comment: @rossum Nevermind, I just figured out why.

Comment: OT: Please, in the future, try to use more meaningful names other than `input`, `input2` or `f`.

Comment: Gentle observation: I believe both 47 and 53 are prime and are only 3 away from 50; similarly, 23 and 29 are both prime and are only 3 away from 26.  Both 97 and 101 are 2 away from 99; using 101 instead of 97 is fine.

Comment: @Motun: That primes other than 2 and 3 are of the format 6N±1 is a fact of life — it is easily demonstrable.  Numbers of the format 6N+0, 6N+2, 6N+4 are all self-evidently even and therefore not prime; numbers of the format 6N+3 are self-evidently multiples of 3; that leaves numbers of the format 6N+1 and 6N+5 (or 6N-1) as the only possible primes.  Not all numbers of the format 6N±1 are prime; for example, 25 = 6*4+1 but is not prime.  But a number that is bigger than 3 that isn't of the 6N±1 format is definitively a composite number.

Comment: If one of the inputs is prime, is that 'the closest prime' and the difference is 0, or do you have to find the next higher or next lower prime and count that difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, that was exactly what I've figured out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is the <strike>compile</strike><sup>1</sup> time should be less than 4 secs and I can't get it under 5 s.

There are *many* potential optimizations for testing primality.

OP currently iterates [2...n)

```
// slow
for ( i = 2 ; i<n ; i++) 
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
```

Only [2...sqrt(n)] needed.

```
// faster
for ( i = 2; i <= n/i; i++) {
  if (n%i == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Other problems may exist, yet the above will speed code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Certainly run time is the issue here.